IIS 10 Web.config to block search engines from crawling pdfs gives status 500
My website is hosted on Azure  App services (formerly Azure websites).
I'm wish to prevent web crawlers from indexing pdf files in subfolder "x" of wwwroot folder.
Below is the web.config file, which I put inside that "x" folder. The webpage that is supposed to return the PDF instead is returning status 500. Does anyone see any issue with the code? If not, maybe I could research how to do Failed Request Tracing in Azure and add result later.
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <configuration>
   <system.webServer>
    <httpProtocol>
     <rewrite>
      <outboundRules>
       <rule name="X-Robots-Tag: noindex to .pdf">
         <match serverVariable="RESPONSE_X_Robots_Tag" pattern=".*" />
           <conditions>
            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" pattern="\.pdf$" />
           </conditions>
           <action type="Rewrite" value="noindex"/>
         </rule>
       </outboundRules>
      </rewrite>
     </httpProtocol>
  </system.webServer
</configuration>


If you hit 500.19 errors then you made typical mistakes in the config file like typos. That doesn’t require further any discussion but please go back to official document to learn the basics. You’d better set up a local machine to test such with IIS/Windows to speed up troubleshooting.

I have corrected the obvious typos and updated the question.  I still get the 500 status response . For now, I will solve the issue by resorting to HTML with . It's unfortunate  Microsoft discontinued the ability to connect to a site hosted in Azure web app from an Azure VM to use IIS Manager GUI, which allowed to easily set rules without needing an on-premises server.

The status 500 error was resolved after I removed  
 

